# Eclipse plugin hot deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin, and I test it launching a secondary Eclipse instance using `Run As -> Eclipse Application` in my project.

So far so good. However, every time I make a source code change (in Java) I need to close this secondary Eclipse instance and start it again to see my code changes being run.

Do you know of any **hot deploy option for an Eclipse plugin**? It would save me time since Eclipse is slow to load back again and again.

I guess I got used to Tomcat that implements hot deploy. The moment you save your Java source file Tomcat automatically deploys it behind the scenes. It doesn't deploy the whole application, but just the modified class -- something that takes just a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using "`Debug`" instead of "`Run`" should be enough.
If this doesn't work, check in the Preferences in `Java > Debug` that "`Enable hot code replace`" is on.
Also make sure that "`Build Automatically`" is selected in the "`Project`" menu. (Or manually invoke "`Build`" after saving)

Comment: Can't believe it! It was there all the time and I didn't see it. Thank you.

Comment: I just spent 3 hours trying to figure out why my project suddenly stopped hot-reloading. Turns out, I unchecked this option by mistake at some point. Thank you very much.

Comment: "`Hot code replace`" doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe only plain java?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting application in Debug mode and make sure you have "spring-boot-devtools" maven dependecny in your pom.xml

Comment: Feel free to mention, how to accomplish that